# Keras: cpu usage 20% and high memory usage even when models run on GPU

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I load three Keras Mobilenets models for inference on Nvidia 1080 GPU with memory fraction set to 0.35. (Tensorflow backend)
I notice that GPU load and GPU memory raise as expected.
However, while loading models and inference, I notice CPU usage and RAM allocation to increase until they reach 22% and 2GB respectively.
Inference for all models is inside while loop.

Is this normal?

Comment: Yes, there is no reason to think it is not normal

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro So models are loaded in ram as well as gpu memory?

Comment: Of course, data has to be loaded somewhere. Note that this question is vague, as there is no detail as to which model, GPU, etc. It varies with model size.